# Why MarketingCloud and SFMC fail only in Release?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, ios

I'm trying last versions `sfmc-sdk-ios (1.0.2)` and `MarketingCloudSDK-iOS (8.0.2)`. When compiling and uploading to testflight sdks doesn't work.

The configuration is like this:

```
SFMCSdk.initializeSdk(ConfigBuilder()
                                .setPush(
                                    config: configuration,
                                    onCompletion: { result in
                                       
                                    }
                                ).build())
```

In Debug is ok, `onCompletion` is called and `SFMCSdk.mp.getStatus()` is operational, but  `Release` the `SFMCSdk.mp.getStatus()` is failed, onCompletion is never called.

- Edited to add debug info from testflight

```
SFMCSdk.setLogger(logLevel: .debug)
```

```
SDK initializing with version: 417
Starting Module initialization: MarketingCloudSDK.PushModule with version compatibility: 8.0.2 - 8.9.9
Failed to initialize MarketingCloudSDK.PushModule due to module version incompatibility caused by semantic versioning issue. Example: 1.0 vs 1.0.0. Semantic versioning must be aligned between the interface and module. Provided version: 416, supported versions: >= 8.0.2 <= 8.9.9
Setting `[“LAST_OPENED_DATE”: “2022-01-04 16:09:38 GMT-03:00"]` as attributes for all modules triggered.
Message `IdentityEvent` received on the event bus.
```

```
SFMCSdk.state()
```

```
{
  "modules" : {
    "cdp" : {
      "compatibility" : "1.9.0 - 2.9.9",
      "name" : "cdp",
      "pendingOperations" : "undefined",
      "status" : "inactive",
      "version" : "unavailable"
    },
    "push" : {
      "compatibility" : "8.0.2 - 8.9.9",
      "name" : "push",
      "pendingOperations" : "undefined",
      "properties" : {
        "details" : "{\n  \"iOS Data Protection\" : {\n    \"Protected Data Available\" : \"true\",\n    \"File Protection Type\" : {\n\n    }\n  }\n}"
      },
      "status" : "failed",
      "version" : "417"
    }
  },
  "version" : "417"
}
```

This 417 is the App Build, should be of sdk version, right?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming You are using same configuration both locally and via test flight. Is it possible that for the debugging purposes You could turn on detailed logs? This may shed some light on what is the issue.

To enable logs please add the following line before trying to initialize the SDK. Logger is independent of the SDK being up and running.

```
SFMCSdk.setLogger(logLevel: .debug)
```

You could also add custom log outputter to capture logs in a different way, such as:

```
// Crate Custom Log Outputter
class MyCustomLogOutputter: LogOutputter {
    @objc open override func out(level: LogLevel, subsystem: String, category: LoggerCategory, message: String) {
        // custom log outputting
    }
}
    
// then enable logger:
SFMCSdk.setLogger(logLevel: .debug, logOutputter: MyCustomLogOutputter())
```

On Completion should be called regardless if the sdk was initialized or not as it should indicate success, error, timeout or if it was cancelled. Hence it looks like logs could tell what is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited it adding the debug info, didn't see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: We are using `sfmc-sdk-ios (1.0.1) and MarketingCloudSDK-iOS (8.0.1)` in prod, but we have other problem, app crash for some of our users:

```
Fatal Exception: com.salesforce.security.keychainException
dictionaryItemFromKeychain: Error attempting to look up keychain item: errSecInteractionNotAllowed
```

So we try update to solve that

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Please see v8.0.3

Comment: From my own experience I wanted to add that SPM has a quite strong caching system and more than often it seemed like I am downloading new artifact, while in fact it was my cache. I would recommend clearing the derived data and restarting Xcode if You want to be sure You are pulling in new artifact and not a cached version.

Comment: Log from testflight:

SDK initializing with version: 416
Starting Module initialization: MarketingCloudSDK.PushModule with version compatibility: 8.0.2 - 8.9.9
Failed to initialize MarketingCloudSDK.PushModule due to module version incompatibility caused by semantic versioning issue. Example: 1.0 vs 1.0.0. Semantic versioning must be aligned between the interface and module. Provided version: 416, supported versions: >= 8.0.2 <= 8.9.9
Setting `[“LAST_OPENED_DATE”: “2022-01-04 16:09:38 GMT-03:00"]` as attributes for all modules triggered.
Message `IdentityEvent` received on the event bus.

Comment: Make sure You are using proper versions of both SFMCSdk and the PushModule. They must be compatible. I would recommend 1.0.2 for the  SFMCSdk and 8.0.3 for the PushModule. Also, I would recommend to clear the derived data and reopen the xcode when testing locally.

Comment: We are testing using 1.0.2 and 8.0.3 versions. Some problem. we have this logs
{"modules" : {"cdp" : {"compatibility" : "1.9.0 - 2.9.9","name" : "cdp","pendingOperations" : "undefined","status" : "inactive","version" : "unavailable"},"push" : {"compatibility" : "8.0.2 - 8.9.9","name" : "push","pendingOperations" : "undefined","properties" : {
        "details" : "{\n  \"iOS Data Protection\" : {\n    \"Protected Data Available\" : \"true\",\n    \"File Protection Type\" : {\n\n    }\n  }\n}"
      },
      "status" : "failed",
      "version" : "417"
    }
  }, "version" : "417"
}

Comment: It is worth mentioning that testing locally we have no problem, both device and simulator configure correctly. This error only occurs on Release, which is on testflight

Comment: Thanks for the update and state. I have a guess what that could be, I will try to reproduce it on my end to see if I can find a solution.

Comment: This issue is related to the "Manage Version and Build Number" option that is defaulted to "yes" when pushing the archive up to TestFlight. If You do not set it, Apple wouldn't change our Framework's versions and Your SDK should be initialized just as it is when You do it locally.

Comment: This version sfmc-sdk-ios (1.0.3) and MarketingCloudSDK-iOS (8.0.4) solved this problem.

Comment: @MarceloJunior solution was to disable this flag or use another version of sdk? I am running same problem currently, but unfortunately in msbuild there's no option to change Manage Version and Build Number to false.

Comment: @boski, The solution is to either use newer versions of the SDK or to disable automatic versioning when pushing the App to be tested via testflight. SDK was verifying integrity and versions using Apple designated parameter and unfortunately Apple changes it on flight if it is enabled. So when You see a prompt "App Store Connect distribution options" > "Manage Version and Build Number" (disable this option).

Comment: @SandraTopczewska thanks. I find out that our release configuration actually works fine. For disabling version it's difficult because we're using msbuild in our fastlane to create iOS file, where alredy this is set to true and I don't have option to disable it. 

For bumping from 7.X to 8.X I am working on bindings, got couple of issues when running Sharpie, so it's not easy fix :)

Comment: @boski the latest SDK should now have this issue. It was fixed, so You should be ready to go. I just wanted to outline what was the problem so You have a better understanding on the case. Good luck on Your project!