# MarketingCloudSDK iOS 8.0.2 - Unable to upload to App Store Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, ios, mobilepush-ios, xcode

I have an iOS app that uses the MarketingCloudSDK. I have updated to SDK to the latest version (8.0.2), removing the pod from Podfile and adding both SFMCSDK and MarketingCloudSDK through Swift Package Manager (just like the documentation [says](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-migration.html)). Apart from that, I copied the MarketingCloudSDK.bundle file from the SDK file and pasted it in the project folder.

[image: Project folder containing MarketingCloudSDK.bundle and both SFMCSDK and MarketingCloudSDK Swift Package Manager dependencies]

Everything looks to be working fine both in the simulator and the physical device, but I get an error when I try to upload the app to App Store.
This is the error:

[image: Error when trying to upload app to App Store Connect]

Is there any fix for this? I need to upload it to App Store Connect, so testers can download it using TestFlight.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 2021-01-11**

After trying the new version v8.0.3, I still get the same errors. Checking the content of the IPA I can see what the error states: the MarketingCloudSDK.framework is included into the MarketingCloudSDK.framework:

[image: IPA content]

Comment: A fix is coming for this.  Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Please see v8.0.3

Comment: Hello @BillMote I have tested with the new version v8.0.3, but I still get the same errors :(

Comment: Relaying to our iOS team.

Comment: SPM holds a very strong cache, so please make sure that You downloaded new 8.0.3 and You do not refer to cached version. On github, there's no Frameworks folder in the MarketingCloudSDK.framework structure. You can try to clean build folder (cmd + shift + k), remove the derived data (rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData), close and reopen Xcode. Then try downloading the package again. This should force fresh download. 

If using newer Xcode, You can also download 8.0.3 from github and reference it "locally".

Comment: Thank you very much! It works well with version 8.0.3 after cleaning the cache!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, a workaround I did was to use these two sdks manually and remove some things like this:

1. Download the version you need: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/sfmc-sdk-ios/tags and https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/tags
2. Remove MarketingCloudSDK from MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/Sources/MarketingCloudSDKResources/Resources/MarketingCloudSDK.bundle
3. Remove folder Frameworks (contains SFMCSDK.framework) from MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/MarketingCloudSDK/MarketingCloudSDK.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7_armv7s/MarketingCloudSDK.framework/Frameworks/SFMCSDK.framework/
4. Remove folder Frameworks (contains SFMCSDK.framework) from MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/MarketingCloudSDK/MarketingCloudSDK.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/MarketingCloudSDK.framework/Frameworks/SFMCSDK.framework/
5. Make Embed & Sign for SFMCSDK and MarketingCloud

I know it's not ideal, but it's what we have for now until the fix in these sdks has been deployed

I recommend 8.0.1 and 1.0.1, in 8.0.2 and 1.0.2 [I have this problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/365600/why-marketingcloud-and-sfmc-fail-only-in-release) but I still don't know if I can solve it regardless of the sdks

Comment: A fix is coming for this.  Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Please see v8.0.3